# Python program gives wrong output when use break statement inside while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, ubuntu-14.04, break

I am using break statement inside while loop to exit from while loop. But it gives wrong output. I don't know why this occurs. Here is the code I have used:

```
def func():
    print "You have entered yes"
t='yes' or 'Y' or 'y' or 'Yes' or 'YES'
while True:
    r=raw_input("Enter any number:")
    if t=='r':
        func()
    else:
        break
print "Program End"
```

**Update:**

When I put **Yes** it should give :
 ***You have entered yes*** , but control goes to ***break*** statement. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `t = 'y' or 'Y' ...` in your code because when you use `or` it checks the validity. Try this code and I am pretty sure it will work.

```
 def func():
     print "You have entered yes"
 t=('yes', 'Y', 'y', 'Yes', 'YES')
 while True:
     r=raw_input("Enter any number:")
     if r in t:
         func()
     else:
         break
 print "Program End"
```

Comment: Please don't use txtspeak on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "because when you use `or` it checks the validity"? what?

Comment: @kindall It means that when you use `or` it check if the first statement in true in this  case a string which is always true

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if t=='r':
```

to

```
if t==r:
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: according to u I have changed it but still it gives the wrong output

Answer (score 0):

First, you're checking if `t` is equal to the string literal `'r'` and not the variable `r`, so in theory what you want is `if t==r`

However, this won't work. What you're looking for is a list, like the following:

```
def func():
    print "You have entered yes"
t= ['yes','Y','y','Yes','YES']
while True:
    r=raw_input("Enter any number:")
    if r in t:
        func()
    else:
        break
print "Program End"
```

Answer (score -1):

When executing
t=='r'
you are comparing variable to a **string** r (this exact one character only), not to r variable.